# What algorithm is best for resource gathering in an RTS game in quickest time?

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, mathematical-foundations, computer-games

Though the concept can be for many RTS games but lets use the specific system of 'age of empires'. For simplicity one resource will be considered. Food.
So in the game there are villagers who gather resources. And resource food is used to create new villagers.

Lets say it costs **x** (ex: 50 unit) amount of food to create 1 villagers which takes **t**(ex: 30 sec) amount of time to make. Each villager can gather **n** (ex:15unit/min) amount of resource per minute.

The goal is to determine the best strategy to have **y**(ex:5000 unit) amount of food in stock in shortest amount of time.

Creating new villagers improves resource gather rate. But it also takes away from resource stock.

What algorithm or math can be used to determine the fastest way to get to certain amount of resource.

I should mention there is a starting number of resources and villagers. Lets say we start with 100 units of food and 1 villager. Since each villager takes 50 units to make. Initially we can queue at most 2 villagers. They are created sequentially. We will have to wait until there is enough food to create new villager.

Comment: How does creation work?  Does it happen in parallel, or must it happen sequentially?  Can I start creating 100 villagers immediately, and then after $t$ I've gone from 0 to 100 villagers?

Comment: Hello you can put villagers to be created on queue if you have enuogh resources. Lets say you start out with 100 units of food. That means you can only queue 2 villagers at that time. And wait for the working villagers to gather enough resource to make new villagers. So another thing I should add are starting resources and villager number. lets say it was 100 units and 1 villager respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the information, and for editing your question.  Please don't use "edit:", and don't just append more information to the end; instead we would prefer that you revise the question so it has all information needed and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Please include all information in the question -- don't leave just some information in the comment.  Yes, it does seem appropriate revise the question to specify the starting resources and villagers.